# Coldfusion session variables usage

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-9

I have few doubts on coldfusion session scope variables usage.
I am using Jquery calendar to show the daily/scheduled events per monthly basis. The event detail rows(json records) are saved in cfm array variable, when user click on next/previous month it is going to make an ajax call and will be getting a new cfm array variable with required event records. Initially I tried to store the previous search events array in browser localstorage but unable to do it properly as the size of array exceeds 8MB and the browser limit should be below 5MB(in chrome, it varies based on browsers), even though using compress technique also having issues in IE browser, finally I want to save the last 6 cfm arrays(earlier search events data) in session scope and at the time of saving 7th array I deleted the first events array.  Please suggest whether we can proceed this or is there any other scope like client rather than session scope. I am working in coldfusion 9 environment.

Comment: Sounds like you are storing too much data (event description/text?). The session scope generally isn't suited for storing large datasets as variables survive until session expiry (usually 20+ minutes), thus end up in old generation and fill up the heap very quickly if you have an unexpected high amount of sessions (peak traffic). Did you consider reducing the search events to references only, like IDs, and resolve them at runtime when actually needed?

Comment: Try to keep the data push to below 10,000k. 100,000k tops

Comment: Hi Can we convert coldfusion arrays as compressed format(may be we can't do this) and each array size I am trying to put in cfm session is of size 8 to 9MB.

Comment: 8MB of JSON is a LOT of data.

It seems that you either have a lot of events each month or each event has a lot of data attached to it. Is this data coming from a database? If so, you may want to look into caching the query results.

Comment: Hi @ScottStroz, these records are from DB, but after getting the records for each record I need to add color, start , end and description attributes, so I am thinking instead of caching the query results I want to save the final processed array of query result into cfm session variable for last 9 searches. Can we use session scope to store the event arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't store that much data in session, you are asking for problems. You could maybe serialize the results into JSON and save that to DB but I am not sure you will gain any performance boost from that. My only suggestion at this point is to find a way to trim the data.

Comment: Hi @ScottStroz, Thank you, except JSON serialization and DB , If any other way(using other scopes rather than session), please suggest. In flex application the caching of previous search results are maintaining with out issues, may be flex internally supports some features suitable to it. Currently we are migrating flex modules to extjs/jquery+CFM modules, the same caching logic in flex can not be achievable in either javascript or coldfsuion.

Comment: No matter what shared scope in CF you store this data, you will run into the same issue. My guess is that the Flex application stored that data locally in the Flex app. I am still curious about the data you are sending to the client. As I noted 8MB of data is a LOT of information in JSON

Comment: Hi @ScottStroz, the records in the array are the cells(mailing records) details like cellid,cellname, mailing id,mailingname, createddate, maileddate....details, some details like Id, Title,Start fields are used for fullcalendar, so each cell record in array contains 10 columns, and for one of the client per month there exists 10000 to 18000 cells, in calendar for monthly view I need to get all the cells from table and at the time of processing I should add the required additional columns for calendar purpose, and saved all these in cfm array &send this cfmarray to jquerycode through Ajax call

Comment: The issue is the searched data is in cfm array,If user goes to other month and return to visited month we should show the cached data instead of new DB request as it takes 1.5 minutes time, So to achieve the cached data I want to save cfm array in session scope, and whenever the user re-visit the visited month just use the session saved array. Now I changed this idea and saved cfm array in javascript array(in compressed way), so now the size decreases a lot and want to save the last 9 visits only, and in JS array one more option is when the page gets refreshed JS array erases automatically.

Comment: Means in Calendar module(It is one of the module in my application) navigate between months view I can save the last 9 user search results in JS compressed arrays, and when user want to leave the current calendar module and navigate to other modules using some JS code I can remove the JS arrays OR refreshing the same page removes JS variables automatically as this is not the case with cfm session variables, the session variables exists till the active session of current user ends, and also not able to compress the cfm array as like JS array. Please share your thoughts @ScottStroz .

Comment: My thoughts are...you are pulling back and trying to store too much data. If you need that data to view details if a user selects an event, maybe you should only retrieve what you need to display items in the calendar and then make another call to get all the details when the user clicks/selects an event.

Comment: The data which I am trying to save in JS compressed array is of limited details only, still surprise how the flex application manages the cache functionality.